# How do I trigger a blocking function when a new user registers to check that their email address is in a collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a flutter app using firebase and google cloud. The organization providing the app to their users uploads a list of users that are able to register and create an account. When a user goes to register I want two things to happen:

1. They are given an error message if their email address and ID number do not match an existing document with email and ID field values
2. Existing fields, like their department and deck number that are in the collection uploaded by the organization are copied to their new user profile

Answer (score 1):

I would write a cloud v2 function. The [documentation has some great examples of how to block registration.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events#common-scenarios) What you would want to do is in the `beforeUserCreated` method, look up the field in firestore to validate that their email. You can get their email through the [AuthBlockingEventType](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events#getting_user_and_context_information) additionalUserInfo field which should provide the username (email in this case) to compare against the firestore database.

Deploying an AuthBlocking function is the same deployment as any other function.

Once deployed, you will need to remember to [register your blocking function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events#register_a_blocking_function) for it to take effect.

As far as updating their user profile information, you could just use another cloud function to listen for a database change once the user is registered and then copy that data over.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I will check all of that out. Can you point me in the right direction of anyone that might do some hourly work to help on this?

Comment: I do not unfortunately

Comment: @Chris see my profile. There are many ways of handling this but as Alexander says blocking functions have made this even easier